# Python Groupby and Count

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on create a sankey plot and have the raw data mapped so that I know source and target node. I'm having an issue with grouping the source & target and then counting the number of times each occurs. E.g. using the table below finding out how many time 0 -> 4 occurs and recording that in the dataframe.

```
index event_action_num  next_action_num
227926  0   6
227928  1   5
227934  1   6
227945  1   7
227947  1   6
227951  0   7
227956  0   6
227958  2   6
227963  0   6
227965  1   6
227968  1   5
227972  3   6
```

Where I want to send up is:

```
event_action_num next_action_num count_of
0    4  1728
0    5  2382
0    6  3739
etc
```

Have tried:

```
df_new_2 = df_new.groupby(['event_action_num', 'next_action_num']).count()
```

but doesn't give me the result I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `agg('size')` instead of `count()`:

```
df_new_2.groupby(['event_action_num', 'next_action_num']).agg('size')
```

For your sample data output will be:

[image: Output]